# Solve race condition during semaphore initialization

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore

I have an array that must be shared between threads, protected by a semaphore. I've put the initialization code inside a function that can be called multiple times, a "constructor", as follows:

```
#include <stdbool.h> //for bool
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t global_mutex;
char global_array[N]; // Protected with global_mutex

struct my_struct *new_my_struct(){
    static bool is_init = false; // This will be initialized only once, right?
    if (!is_init){                         // 1
        sem_init(&global_mutex, 0, 1);     // 2
        sem_wait(&global_mutex);           // 3
        if (!is_init){                     // 4
           is_init = true;                 // 5
           ... initialize global_array ... // 6
        }
        sem_post(&global_mutex);           // 7
    }

    ... proceed on the create and return a my_struct pointer ...
}
```

In an ideal world, a thread would run from 1 to 7, initialize the array and exit the critical region. Even if another thread had stopped in 2, the test in 4 would be false and the array wouldn't be overwritten. I haven't thinked much of what would happen if a thread stuck in 1 and reinitialized the semaphore, but I believe it isn't of much concern *as long as `is_init` be set to true by the first thread to run!*

Now, there is a race condition if a thread stops in 4, and another one runs from the beggining to completion, initializing and populating the `global_array`. When the thread stopped at 4 runs, it will reinitialize the array and delete the state stored by the first thread.

I would like to know if there is any way to not suffer that race condition (maybe a clever use of `static`?) or if I should separate the initialization code from the constructor and use it in the main thread, when there's no concurrency.

This code is in use and I haven't suffered from a race condition yet. However, as I know its possible, I'd wish to correct it.

Comment: As the array is global, why not initialize it and the semaphore _before_ you start your threads? Then you don't have to worry about race conditions in the initialization code.

Comment: Is it really necessary to check (!is_init) twice? ;o
And yes, the static bool will be treated as a global variable in your function's scope.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Yes, a thread can stop in 3 and another proceed until 5. Then the first thread won't enter the if and the second will proceed to initialize the array. Oops, you just uncovered a bug! The first thread can proceed to the function with an uninitialized array!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'd wish not to, for aestethics and ease of use. You don't see many standard libraries requiring you to call an initialization function in the main thread before using its other functionalities, and its safer not to require the user to remember to do so.

Comment: "it will reinitialize the array and delete the state stored by the first thread" actually it will re-initialize with undefined behavior. But since it's bad either way, what you said is close enough for this example.

Comment: I have a hard time thinking of any library that _don't_ have some kind of open, create or init function. For some you even have to call an init function _before_ you can call the open function (e.g. MySQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the real use of the semaphore is really as a mutex, use just that `pthread_mutex_t`. These can be initialized statically, so your problem would disappear.

The syntax would be

```
pthread_mutex_t global_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

If you really need a dynamic initialization of a global object, have a look into `pthread_once`. This is the type (`pthread_once_t`) and function that is foreseen by POSIX for such a task.

Comment: Do I need to destroy a mutex initialized this way?

Comment: @BrunoKim, no you shouldn't call destroy on it. There should be exactly one destroy per init call.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do thread-safe lazy initialization, but this isn't one of them.

`pthread_once` is one way, and using a global mutex that's actually a mutex (initialized statically) to synchronize the initialization is another. Implementations might guarantee thread-safe initialization of `static` local variables, but don't have to (at least, they didn't prior to C11 and I haven't checked that).

However you synchronize the actual initialization, though, *double-checked locking is not guaranteed to work in C or in Posix*. It's a data race to check a flag in one thread, that was set in another thread, without some kind of synchronization in *both* threads. The implementation of `pthread_once` should do its best to be fast in the common case that the initialization has already been done. *If* your implementation guarantees thread-safe intialization of function-scoped static variables, then that will also do its best. Unless you really know what you're doing (e.g. you're implementing `pthread_once` yourself for some new system), use one of those in preference to rolling your own attempt to avoid costly locking in the common case.

Comment: Is general double-checking ok, though? I first learned it in Java, and am using in my code to avoid locking the entire array during reads, like this: `for element in array{ if (element is desired){ lock(); if (element is desired){ do_stuff(element);} unlock(); } }`

Comment: @BrunoKim: it's fine as long as `element_is_desired` is restricted to the thread that the code is running in. But then you wouldn't normally need the second `if`, because normally there'd be no way that calling `lock()` could change `element_is_desired`. If `element_is_desired` is changed from another thread then no, it is not OK. Your thread could see the value "false" long after some other thread thinks it has set it to "true".